# how to count first letter of each word in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, count, bar-chart

How can I get the count first letter in each word in d3 barchart? For example, the words are, This is tiger  - for this, I want to get the count of first letter in each word. The result should be visualized in barchart. I've attached the article link here. http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/e8c0d6abc0a8d52d4b11

Answer (score -1):

d3

Checkout this link https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#selection_size

It contains d3's documentation on 'selection'

You could also visit this same link you posted here http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/e8c0d6abc0a8d52d4b11#index.html and study the code
The code that was used to make the bar chart was written there